# Azure Media Player HLS support

Tags: azure, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I'm using Azure Media Player in my project to play Azure Media Service assets and it works great for that. However, I'd also need to play some HLS content within the same project and would like to use the same player.

Microsoft claims that AMP supports HLS, but when I put any HLS source into it and set the the format to HLS, I'm ending up with a "No compatible source was found for this media." error.

Has anyone managed to successfully play HLS content with AMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Media Player only supports playing content from Media Services.  If you want to use a single player for any HLS source including non Media Services content then you'll probably want to use a different player like Shaka, Video.js, or JWPlayer.  That said, you might have success with AMP if you disable to URL rewriter as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-url-rewriter.

Answer (score 3):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-playback-technology. AMP uses "html5" and "html5FairPlayHLS" for HLS playback which both rely on native HLS support vs support via javascript. If you need to use HLS on windows / or older versions of android you would need to use another player.